# Join query shows results based only on one match

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, join

So here is my query

```
SELECT `c`.`location`, `c`.`id`, `c`.`user_id`, `c`.`date`, `c`.`attachment`, 
`ud`.`first_name`, `ud`.`last_name`, 
`a`.`file_name`, `a`.`folder_name`, `a`.`server_key`, `a`.`type` FROM `content`
AS `c` INNER JOIN `users_details` AS `ud` ON ud.user_id = c.user_id INNER JOIN
`attachments` AS `a` ON c.id = a.content_id WHERE (c.location = 'New York')
```

I'm looking to also include in the results data from the attachments table, the problem is that not any data row from the table `content` has an attachment, If a post has an attachments it saves in the content table in the row attachment with an 1, and 0 if it doesn'T have an attachment.

Now the problem is that my query only displays data that has attachments, I guess this problem comes from the join with the attachments table.

So how can I do this so I have the following output: kinda merge the data together to show posts that have uploads and also does that don't and also show data from the attachments table from those which have uploads. kinda like this:

```
  [0] => array(11) {
    ["location"] => string(15) "New York"
    ["id"] => string(2) "25"
    ["user_id"] => string(1) "1"
    ["date"] => string(10) "1364348772"
    ["attachment"] => string(1) "1"
    ["first_name"] => string(8) "John"
    ["last_name"] => string(7) "Doe"
    ["file_name"] => string(36) "c2638acdac24dc2efe4e5971db5f4cc5.jpg"
    ["folder_name"] => string(13) "5133b99030ac4"
    ["server_key"] => string(1) "1"
    ["type"] => string(1) "1"
  }
  [1] => array(11) {
    ["location"] => string(15) "New York"
    ["id"] => string(2) "26"
    ["user_id"] => string(1) "1"
    ["date"] => string(10) "1364348812"
    ["attachment"] => string(1) "0"
    ["first_name"] => string(8) "John"
    ["last_name"] => string(7) "Doe"
    ["file_name"] => string(36) ""
    ["folder_name"] => string(13) ""
    ["server_key"] => string(1) ""
    ["type"] => string(1) ""
  }
```

Comment: I guess I need to do a left join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem you just need to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` the attachments table like this:

```
SELECT
  `c`.`location`,
  `c`.`id`,
  `c`.`user_id`,
  `c`.`date`,
  `c`.`attachment`, 
  `ud`.`first_name`,
  `ud`.`last_name`, 
  `a`.`file_name`,
  `a`.`folder_name`,
  `a`.`server_key`,
  `a`.`type`
FROM `content` AS `c`
INNER JOIN `users_details` AS `ud`
  ON ud.user_id = c.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN `attachments` AS `a`
  ON c.id = a.content_id
WHERE c.location = 'New York'
```

The `OUTER JOIN` will return all results regardless as to whether there is an `a.content_id` that matches to `c.id`.  Those selected fields from the attachment table will simply show as `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT `c`.`location`, `c`.`id`, `c`.`user_id`, `c`.`date`, `c`.`attachment`, 
`ud`.`first_name`, `ud`.`last_name`, 
`a`.`file_name`, `a`.`folder_name`, `a`.`server_key`, `a`.`type` FROM `content`
AS `c` INNER JOIN `users_details` AS `ud` ON ud.user_id = c.user_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
`attachments` AS `a` ON c.id = a.content_id WHERE (c.location = 'New York')
```

There is a good [Wikipedia page about joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).